# Django get authors in serie through book-object

Tags: django, django-models

For a hobby project I am building a django-app that displays the books in a private collection.

I have 3 models relevant to this question: Serie, Book and Author:

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
   pass

class Book(models.Model):
   authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)

class Serie(models.Model):
   books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
```

If I have a Serie-object, what is a good way to get all authors in the serie? (Some series in the collection have books written by different authors)

Answer (score 1):

You can work with:

```
Author.objects.filter(book__serie=my_serie)
```

So if *`my_serie`* is *Conan*, it will return as authors *Poul Anderson*, *Leonard Carpenter*, *Lin Carter*, etc. as `Author` objects.

If an `Author` wrote to multiple books in the `my_serie`, it will appear multiple times. You can prevent that with [**`.distinct()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#distinct):

```
Author.objects.filter(book__serie=my_serie).distinct()
```

Comment: Thanx for the working answer! Didn't know you could filter through multiple many-to-many like that.